# Adding doubles together

Tags: c#, double

I have a text files that contain two numbers which represent monetary amounts.
When I read them in as doubles, let's say:
double a = 73.7926
double b = 1.1

and add them together I get as a result: `74.892599999999987`
where I would expect to have `74.8926`

Any idea why this is and what I need to do to have my expected result without rounding ?

Comment: Can you show the code for parsing the numbers?

Comment: Although I am pretty sure you won't read it http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Did you try printing the result ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that particular task you may use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) type instead of double.

```
decimal a = 73.7926M; 
decimal b = 1.1M;
decimal d = a + b;
```

You should see: [Tutorial to Understand IEEE Floating-Point Errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980)

Answer (score 3):

> ### [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
>
> So you’ve written some absurdly simple code, say for example:
>
> ```
> 0.1 + 0.2
> ```
>
> and got a really unexpected result:
>
> ```
> 0.30000000000000004
> ```
>
> Maybe you asked for help on some forum and got pointed to a long article with lots of formulas that didn’t seem to
>   help with your problem.
>
> Well, this site is here to:
>
> - Explain concisely why you get that unexpected result
> - Tell you how to
>     deal with this problem
> - If you’re interested, provide in-depth
>     explanations of why floating-point numbers have to work like that and
>     what other problems can arise
>
> You should look at the Basic Answers
>   first - but don’t stop there!

If you want to represent money, you should work with decimals (floating-points with base 10).

Answer (score 0):

Use Decimal instead of double. Why, you can read here: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5

Answer (score 0):

```
result = Math.Round(result, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```